# Theming in Angular 7 with Custom CSS Properties and SASS

Tags: css, angular, sass, theming, angular7

I am working on an app that uses Custom CSS Properties with SASS to implement theming and it needs to work in IE 11. I have had a look at [this library](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill) but I can't really discern how to configure it properly.

I have an Angular app and we are switching themes by using class selectors on `:root body`. The themes contain the variables. The code is working perfectly in Chrome et al, but doesn't work in IE 11. What are the steps to get the library to do its magic and fix my CSS? I know there is a lot of documentation around the `cssVars()` method, and I have looked at all the dependent projects; but I still can't get it working!

I am using the following format for my variables:

```css
$variables: (
  --box-shadow-color: var(--box-shadow-color),
  --page-background-color: var(--page-background-color),
}
```

and giving them these default values:

```css
:root body {
  --box-shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  --page-background-color: #{$light-grey};
}
```

and then swapping them in and out by using classes:

```css
:root body.theme-johnlewis {
  --box-shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  --page-background-color: #{$color-red};
}
```

Is this the right format to be using?